# How bind link to call java script function in FPDF

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, fpdf

I am trying to call javascript function by clicking on link but no success.

```
class PDF_AutoPrint extends PDF_JavaScript
{
    function alert(){
        // write some JavaScript code
        $js = 'app.alert("JavaScript Popup Example", 3, 0, "Welcome");';
        $js.= 'console.log("heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");';
}

$pdf = new PDF_AutoPrint();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 20);
$pdf->Text(90, 50, 'call js function!');
$pdf->alert();

$link = $pdf->AddLink();
$pdf->Write(5,'here',$link);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetLink($link);

$pdf->Output();
```

Above code is working, alert message comes when file opens and then by clicking on 'here' it will take to another next page.

**I modified it like this so if someone click on 'here' there will be alert window but following code does not works.**

```
$pdf = new PDF_AutoPrint();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 20);
    $pdf->Text(90, 50, 'call js function!');
    $alert = $pdf->alert();

    $pdf->Write(5,'here',$alert);
    $pdf->Output();
```

Any clue how to call java script function by clicking on the link/text.

Comment: I am stuck with the same problem. I tried to use the javascript protocol, that is set $link = 'javascript:console.log("It works");' but it doesn't work unfortunately, the link in the PDF is not clickable at all, if the $link variable is set to something starting with "javascript:"...